# How to see a collision from an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, encryption, hash, sha

I need to find a string I can put into my program to have the same hash value as;

```
HOTTEST LINDA ONE OF THE MANY ABSTRACT PAINTINGS BY THIS FAB ROCKER DEPICTS   HIS FIRST WIFE SUNBATHING"
hash value -> 0x1bfdbfe8
```

Here is the algorithm;

```
Input{inStr: a binary string of bytes}
Output{outHash: 32-bit hashcode for the inStr in a series of hex values}
Mask: 0x3FFFFFFF
outHash: 0
for byte in input
  intermediate_value = ((byte XOR 0xCC) Left Shift 24) OR
  ((byte XOR 0x33) Left Shift 16) OR
  ((byte XOR 0xAA) Left Shift 8) OR
  (byte XOR 0x55)
  outHash =(outHash AND Mask) + (intermediate_value AND Mask)
return outHash
```

How do you just look at this algorithm and  find the results are the same no matter what bytes you perform the operation on first. I an't see it...

THANKS

Comment: Since the intermediate value resulting from each byte processed is just added to the hash output, swapping characters within the input should have no effect on the output (since `a + b == b + a`), as a result, any anagram of the input should have the same hash.

Comment: Why is this tagged `sha` (or `encryption` for that matter)?

Answer (score 1):

> How do you just look at this algorithm and find the results are the same no matter what bytes you perform the operation on first.

`intermediate_value` is a pure function of `byte`. Neither the position of the `byte` nor what values precede or follow it affect the `intermediate_value`.

`outHash` is the sum of the intermediate values.

The [commutative law of addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition#Commutativity) tells us that the sum will be the same regardless of the order of the bytes.

So you can re-order the input as you wish - the hash value will stay the same.